# Create adjacency matrix from edge list

Tags: python, graph

Hello i'm trying to code the generation of an adjacency matrix from an edge list but i can't get my code to work and i don't understand why

i've tried inversing the indexes and running it step by step

```py
graph1=[[0,2,3,4],[1,2,4],[0,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[0,2,4]]

def Adjacency(graph):
    index = 0  #Index of the sublist
    matrix = [[0]*len(graph)]*len(graph)
    print(matrix)  
    for sublist in graph:
        for value in sublist:
            print(value)
            matrice[index][value] = 1
        index+=1

    print(matrix)

Adjacence(graphe1)
```

the expected output should be

```
[[1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1]]
```

but instead i got

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

i'm pratically sure that i forgot a small detail but i can't figure it out. 
i'd be glad if somebody could me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change the line:

```
matrix = [[0]*len(graph)]*len(graph)
```

to:

```
matrix = [[0]*len(graph) for i in range(len(graph))]
```

This is becasue when you make an array the way you did it stores them differently and they can edit multiple values at once. Try reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157961/2d-array-of-zeros) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459337/assign-value-to-an-individual-cell-in-a-two-dimensional-python-array)