# Indexing 2 dimensional array in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to change a single item in a 2-dimensional array in python using the syntax `x[2][3]=1` but instead of just changing the item in the 2nd row 3rd column, it ends up changing the values of all of the 3rd column. My code is below:

```
population = [[0]*20]*5

population[2][3] = 1

for row in population:
    print(row)
```

This outputs

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

but I only want

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How would I index the item such that it only changes the 2nd row and 3rd column?

I'm using python 3.7.4 on repl.it

Link here: https://repl.it/@ajqe/2d-array-test

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign value to an individual cell in a two dimensional python array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459337/assign-value-to-an-individual-cell-in-a-two-dimensional-python-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

`population = [[0]*20 for _ in range(5)]`

to generate the lists instead. The method you are using is referencing the same object 5 times, instead of creating 5 separate lists. To check this you can use the `is` operator:

```
>>> population = [[0]*20]*5
>>> population[0] is population[1]
True

>>> population = [[0]*20 for _ in range(5)]
>>> population[0] is population[1]
False
```